# How to customize monaco editor build-in color picker component?

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

Is it possible for us to customize Monaco editor build-in color picker component UI?

Comment: There's a color picker component in Monaco? That's new to me. How do you trigger that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MikeLischke: There is an example here: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-color-provider-example

At the time of writing there is bug in the sample code, so the colour symbols don't show up, but it is easy to fix: Set the `endColumn` value in the code on the left to 2.